# How to implement multiple column drop down using Select2

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I will admit to not being a massively experienced Javascript developer and I have run into a problem with this. I am creating a Select2 box programmatically and it works exactly as I want it to. The only problem is that I don't want the box to scroll i.e. if the list is too long I want it to use multiple columns.

Creating the select2

```
            $("#regionSelector").select2({placeholder: "Filter Results", 
                            allowClear: false,
                            minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
            });
```

I have tried limited the height but not the width of the drop down but this doesn't seem to force it to do anything other than create a scroll bar. Has anyone had any luck doing what I want to achieve?

I have seen talk of using bootstrap to achieve this but I am not entirely clear how this is done. I would post more code snippets but I don't think they are actually relevant to what I want to achieve (if they are I can add more).

Comment: I don't see any examples or indication the select2 supports multiple columns. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: the answer: http://codepen.io/lembitk/pen/Lhkpi