# Select2 multiple columns: breaking changes after version 3.4.5

Tags: python, html, css, django, jquery-select2

Having multiple columns available for selection works well in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/lembitk/pen/qBWONE

(this codepen was given in comment to question:[How to implement multiple column drop down using Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549719/how-to-implement-multiple-column-drop-down-using-select2)

Columns 'titles' and content described by the

```
<optgroup>
```

tags.

[codepen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHcOi.png)

Changing the column width in this CSS works, and updates the results correctly:

```
.select2-results-dept-0 { /* do the columns */
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
```

Copying this code pen (html, css, and js) into a clean local test page presents the options in a single column, with non-selectable section titles provided by the  tags.

As close as I can determine, the difference is only on the version of Bootstrap, Jquery and Select2 libraries in use.  I have tried, successfully, to obtain the Select2@3.4.5 version in use in the codepen: It then works, locally.

I believe it may be that the class select2-results-dept-0 has been renamed/removed - but I have failed to discover to what.

Would you happen to know how to obtain this multiple column effect with later versions of Select2?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked.  What a frustrating day of time on this: answer presented to help others.

Change:

```
.select2-results-dept-0 { /* do the columns */
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
```

to

```
.select2-results__option[role=group]
  float: left ;
  width: 20%;
}
```

And Robert is your mums bro.